# Can i share an image from my app to any other public facebook page ? n how?

Tags: android, image, facebook

Bellow is the code  which enables to share image only within my network on facebokk page.

```
private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){
    Log.e("in sharemethod", "hiiiiii");
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
            .setBitmap(image)
            .setCaption("Give me my codez or I will ... you know, do that thing you don't like!")
            .build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
            .addPhoto(photo)
            .build();
    shareDialog.show(content);}
```

I want to to share an image to the pages not in my facebook network.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not share !

Facebook does not allow it because for this you need access tokens of the pages and if you wanna share through app on pages for this it is needed that the page which are not your network must allow you app to do so.And you also need to get permissions first from the Facebook such as posting permission or etc :)